# Apple Push Notification Service compatible with python 3

Tags: python, django, apple-push-notifications, pyapns

I wish to send push notifications to apple devices. I tried using **[PyAPNs](https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs)**  but there is compatibility issue with python 3. Also a few other packages which I tried are not compatible with python 3.
Can anyone suggest me any package that is compatible with python 3 to send push messages?

Answer (score 0):

If you've created an iOS app you want to send notifications to I don't have an answer for you. But if you just need the notifications I can recommend using Pushover, https://pushover.net/
I use it myself for getting all sorts of different notifications from different devices running python3 scripts, for example notifications from my server when someone connects via SSH or VNC.

Comment: Unfortunately mate, I do need to send notifications to an iOS app.
Thanks for your time anyways.